# convert language of a div

Tags: php

I am recently working in a project. There I need to convert language from English to Japanese by button click event. The text is in a div. Like this:

```
"<div id="sampletext"> here is the text </div>"
"<div id="normaltext"> here is the text </div>"
```

The text is come from database. How can I convert this text easily?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135789/how-can-i-convert-language-of-a-div

Comment: https://translate.google.com/manager/website/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of AJAX and JQuery should do the trick.

- AJAX - Go to the database and get the relevant text string
- JQuery - Change the text in the div, identifying it by class.

Answer (score 0):

Easily? I think not.

You'd need some kind of Javascript to grab the value of the div, then send it to a server-side script where it can be translated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Google API to get google translations. But you would still need to do some AJAX like Nath suggested.